# How do I view the entire call chain from a command?

Tags: evil, debugging, hooks

I am facing weird issues from editing Kotlin code with LSP enabled with `lsp-mode`, in Spacemacs. Everytime I evil-yank and evil-mc-paste a line by `yy` followed by `p`, an empty line is pasted instead. The below demo is where I yank a line and try to paste it three times by pressing `p` repeatedly.

[image: An empty line is being pasted instead of a yanked line.]

I went through every hooks I could think of, to no avail. So, I want to view a whole Elisp call chain triggered by my `spacemacs/evil-mc-paste`, and I think that is the most surefire, if not too general, way of debugging this behavior.

How can I get such call chain information? Or is there a better way of tackling this sort of issue?

Comment: As you want to 'debug' `evil-mc-paste`, I guess you have confirmed that the line is added to the 'evil register' (`SPC SPC evil-show-registers`). I'm not sure, but I guess I would first check if pasting works when using `SPC SPC evil-paste-after`. If that does not work, then it is probably time to read about [using edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Edebug.html), with [Spacemacs keybindings](https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/emacs-lisp/README.html#debugging).

Comment: And maybe also see if someone is available to assist you on [the Spacemacs gitter channel](https://gitter.im/syl20bnr/spacemacs).